# cant copy the yytext with strcpy

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

This is my code

strcpy doesnt copy the yytext

Any suggestion why?

These are my globals

```
char** v; /* array of variables and their values */
int i;
```

some name definition

```
WORD    [a-zA-Z]
DIGIT   [0-9]
```

These are the states

```
<VAL>"\"".+"\"" {int x=sizeof(yytext);
    v[i]=(char*)realloc(v, x*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(v[i],yytext);
    i++;
    BEGIN(INITIAL);}
<VAL>.  { i--;printf("error");}
<SAVE_VAL>{WORD}[{WORD}{DIGIT}_]*   { 
    if (NULL==v){
        v=(char**)realloc(v, 100*sizeof(char*));
        i=0;
    }
    int x=sizeof(yytext);
    v[i]=(char*)realloc(v, x+2);
    strcpy(v[i],yytext);
    i++;
    BEGIN(VAL);
    }

val" " {BEGIN(SAVE_VAL);}
```

This is the yywrap

```
int yywrap(void){
    return 1;

}
```

This is the main

```
int main(void) { 

    yyin=fopen("input.txt","r");   
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
```

This is the loop to print the strings

```
    for (int j=0;j<100;j++){
        if (NULL==v[j])
            break;
        printf("%s",v[j],i);
    }
} 


}
```

I'm tring to run it on 
    val a="asdasd";

I'm expecting it to print
`a`
`asdasd`

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
int x=sizeof(yytext);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `yytext` is of type `char*`; that is, it is a pointer to a character. That means that `sizeof yytext` is either 4 or 8, depending on whether you're compiling on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform. (Or some other pointer length if you have a really unusual architecture.)

It is not the length of the string starting at `yytext`. That would be the standard library function `strlen(yytext)`.

However, you don't need to use that, either, because `flex` has helpfully assigned the length of the token to the global variable `yyleng`.

When you are allocating space for the copy, don't forget that in C *strings are always NUL-terminated*. That means that the allocation for a string must be (at least) one greater than the length of the string, which means you need `yyleng + 1` bytes.